# How to properly connect Stm32 uart tx to rx?

Tags: stm32, uart

I have connected 2 stm32l476 by uart rx to uart tx. The tx transmits continuously data. The rx receives only one time correctly the transmited data and afterwards does read only zeros. I tried to init and deinit uart. I ckecked uart handler cr1 before and after receive which had value 1101. I changed value Cr1 rxne but didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest that you [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: Before you can send/receive, you also need a ground connection and the UARTs on each end must be configured to the same line settings.

Comment: Sends continuously? You probably have an overrun error. When data byte is received by the MCU peripheral (without code's say so, on the physical level), not read, and another data byte arrives. It locks up the peripheral until you clear the overrun flag. Clear the flag before calling receive function, see if anything changes.